# monacaでスリープ機能の制御は出来る？

Tags: monaca

monacaでスマホ用アプリを作成しているのですが、アプリを使用中のときだけ、
画面のスリープ機能をOFFにしたいのですが、monacaでそういった機能をつけることは
できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin

どうやらこちらのプラグインを利用するとできるようです。